# Trigger function when adding a row in an other spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, eventtrigger

I have a problem with triggers in Google App Script. I have a spreadsheet holding my users and other stuff (appSheet), and I have a second spreadsheet that holds all the data (dataSheet).

I also built a script that imports some data from "appSheet" to "dataSheet", and it works pretty well. The problem is I need it to execute automatically when a new row (user) is added in the app sheet. The built-in triggers in Google App Script doesn't allow me to set that kind of trigger.

I set this importing function in the dataSheet, maybe should I set it in the appSheet ? It may seem super easy but I'm a newbie to this :)

Has someone an insight on how to automatically trigger that function ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I also think that this importing function should be done in your appSheet. You can use onEdit() to trigger your importing function, but this might be tricky since you need to make sure that the specific column in the current row was completely filled in with a new user data before the function is called. If this is not clear, you could provide a sample appSheet  so i could give some example. [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: You could investigate Apps Script API.  It allows you to execute scripts remotely.  But in all probability you may want to duplicate some of the functionality in the sheet where the triggers occur.

Comment: @Ronm yep I already checked the documentation about the onEdit but as I want the data to be imported when adding a row, it think I better use a Change trigger, no ?

Comment: @Cooper I don't want to execute the functions remotely, you right. I want no intervention at all so I can scale my app and focus on something else.

Comment: But for change trigger, it can trigger your function when a new row was inserted. But based on my understanding, you actually need to input data in your row. I also think you will not insert a new row and input your data, rather you just need to insert your data on the next blank row?

Comment: How about use a button to trigger your function? example, a new row (user) is added in your app sheet, then click the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys for your answers !
I found a very simple way to achieve this.

Instead of setting the script on the **dataSheet** and having the need of an "onEdit" trigger, I put the script in the **appSheet** and did little modifications.

The script is as followed :

```
function exportData() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var values = ss.getSheetByName('mySourceSheet').getRange('A2:B').getValues();

  var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("myDestinationSpreadsheet");
  var targetSheet = dataSheet.getSheetByName("myDestinationSheet");

  targetSheet.getRange(2,1,values.length,values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

The "2" in the "targetSheet.getRange" meaning I want it to begin in row 2.

Everything runs perfectly now with the built-in triggers in Apps Script.